# Connecting Heroku App to outside database

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have deployed my App to Heroku and I wanted Heroku to connect to an outside PostgreSQL database.

this is my Rails database.yml

```
production:
url: "postgres://postgres:@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"
adapter: PostgreSQL
```

This database works fine in dev environment. But when on Heroku I'm getting a connection refused error. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku ignores your database.yml production settings and uses it's own. Heroku uses the ENV var DATABASE_URL to create the connection. I think you can achieve your goal, if you use the same structure as they use to connect to the heroku pg.

Add ENV var in heroku app settings:

`DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@your-host/db_name`

Add ENV var here: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/settings
Click on "Reveal Config Vars" and add `DATABASE_URL`
[image]

or via CLI:

`heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@your-host/db_name --app your-app-name`

Be sure you have the gem `pg` installed!

Comment: Actually we are just experimenting on Heroku. Sorry I'm new to rails but on my GemFile I have pg included.  Can you point me to the Heroku app settings?

Comment: I added a explanation